# How to compare the ArrayList Object (java class) in JESS?

Tags: jess

This is my main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JessException {
    Rete engine = new Rete();
    engine.batch("template.clp");

    PizzaBase pizzaBase = new PizzaBase();
    pizzaBase.setSize(9);

    PizzaTopping pizzaTopping = new PizzaTopping();
    pizzaTopping.setName("T1");

    PizzaTopping pizzaTopping2 = new PizzaTopping();
    pizzaTopping2.setName("T2");

    PizzaTopping pizzaTopping3 = new PizzaTopping();
    pizzaTopping3.setName("T3");

    List<PizzaTopping> pizzaToppingList = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();
    pizzaToppingList.add(pizzaTopping);
    pizzaToppingList.add(pizzaTopping2);
    pizzaToppingList.add(pizzaTopping3);

    Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
    pizza.setBase(pizzaBase);
    pizza.setPizzaToppingList(pizzaToppingList);

    engine.add(pizzaBase);
    engine.addAll(pizzaToppingList);
    engine.add(pizza);
    engine.eval("(facts)");
    engine.batch("rules.clp");
    engine.reset();
    engine.run();
    engine.eval("(facts)");

}
```

I would like to check the pizza that contain the topping name is "T2" in the pizzaToppingList or not.The rule is shown below

```
(defrule rule1
    (Pizza (pizzaToppingList ?t2) (OBJECT ?a))
    (PizzaTopping (name "T2") (OBJECT ?t2))
     =>
    (printout t "fired")
)
```

But It does not work,because In JESS, slot value of pizzaToppingList is ArrayList(java object).Which means the pizzaToppingList slot is not the Lists value in JESS.

How I solve this problem ? thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll have to call a method of Java's own ArrayList class. A simple way is to use the `test` CE:

```
(defrule rule1
  (Pizza (pizzaToppingList ?ptList) (OBJECT ?a))
  (PizzaTopping (name "T2") (OBJECT ?t2))
  (test  (?ptList contains ?t2) )
=>
  (printout t "fired")
)
```

What you have tried cannot work, since you are using the same binding variable `?t2` for the list and for what might be one of its elements.

Comment: I tied to use your answer but, the program shows the error like this "Bad slot name at token ?ptList"

Comment: Thank you ! I work right now I change from "(eval  (?ptList contains ?t2) )" to (test  (?ptList contains ?t2) )

Comment: Sorry - it is supposed to be test (eval is from another system.) I've edited my answer.